# PHP typehint specialization without actual method declaration

Tags: php

I have the following piece of code all over the place:

```
class Container extends Object implements \IteratorAggregate {

    public function AddObject(Object $object, $instanceKey) {
        ...
    }

    public function AddComponent(Component $component) {
        ...
    }
}

class MenuContainer extends Container {

    public function AddComponent(Menu $component) { // <-- I'm redeclaring the method only because I need to change the typehint
        return parent::AddComponent($component);// I don't do anything useful here
    }

    public function AddObject(Menu $object, $instanceKey) { // <-- I'm redeclaring the method only because I need to change the typehint
        return parent::AddObject($object, $instanceKey); // I don't do anything useful here
    }
}
```

I'm forced to do typehint specialization via method redeclaration because I want to prevent people that are using my code from doing mistake and accidentally adding something incompatible to my menu. So the question: Is there a way of doing typehint specialization without the actual method redeclaration?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specializing your methods, specialize the types you're passing:

```
class Foo { }
class Bar extends Foo { }

class Container extends Object implements \IteratorAggregate {

    public function AddObject(Foo $menu) { }

}

Container::AddObject(new Bar());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but, I think you've missed the point deceze. In your example you allow both "Container::AddObject(new Foo())" and "Container::AddObject(new Bar())". But in my case when the Bar is allowed, the Foo is not allowed. And typehints specialization helps doing that. But it forces me to create lots and lots of fish methods that doesn't do anything usefull except "return parent::AddComponent($component);" So I would like not to create these fish methods in derived class but to change the typehint.

Comment: Here's the link to another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742302/php-with-netbeans-applying-new-phpdoc-without-the-actual-declaration There I've figured out how to change the PhpDoc, now I would like to change the Typehint the same way if it is possible